# Linear Regression in mlr3 with Interactions / Quadratic Terms

Tags: linear-regression, mlr3

I try to fit a linear model with interactions and/or quadratic terms in mlr3 benchmark. Unfortunately, I didn't find a possibility on github or stackexchange. Here is an example:

```
library(mlr3verse)

tskScen <- tsk("mtcars")
msrMSE <- msr("regr.rmse")
rsgScen = rsmp("cv", folds = 4)
learners = lrns(c("regr.lm", "regr.ranger"))
benchdesign = benchmark_grid(tskScen, learners, rsgScen)
bmr = benchmark(benchdesign, store_models = TRUE)
bmr$aggregate(msrMSE)
```

And here is the version info:

```
> mlr3verse_info()
             package version
 1:            bbotk   0.5.1
 2:      mlr3cluster   0.1.2
 3:         mlr3data   0.6.0
 4:      mlr3filters   0.5.0
 5:      mlr3fselect   0.6.1
 6:    mlr3hyperband   0.4.0
 7:     mlr3learners   0.5.1
 8:         mlr3misc  0.10.0
 9:    mlr3pipelines   0.4.0
10:        mlr3proba   0.4.4
11:       mlr3tuning  0.12.1
12: mlr3tuningspaces   0.1.1
13:          mlr3viz   0.5.7
14:          paradox   0.8.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do [parameter transformations](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/technical.html#parameter-transformation) help?

Comment: Thanks @pat-s. Unfortunately, I didn't find something helpful to get interactions into "regr.lm".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regr.rsm` Learner that is available through mlr3extralearners.
See here: https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_learners_regr.rsm.html

Answer (score 0):

So, the only way I've found to do this is with the model matrix pipe op: https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_modelmatrix.html

This allows you to define the formula of the task, like so:

```
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3pipelines)

tskScen <- tsk("mtcars")
pop <- po("modelmatrix", formula = ~ hp * disp * drat) 
tskScen.new <- pop$train(list(tskScen))$output
lm.lrnr <- lrn("regr.lm")
lm.lrnr$train(tskScen.new)
lm.lrnr$predict(tskScen.new)
```

This creates new interaction features in the task which you can then use to train your linear model.